# RecursionError when uploading certain images

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a model with an image input that is to be resized and hashed along with a thumbnail on save. However, I appear to to have created an infinite recursive call. Some images upload, create thumbnails, and generate hashes without issues, but one image causes the program to call `self.thumbnail.save(new_name, img_file)` (the last line of `generate_thumbnail`) endlessly. How can I save the image and avoid the recursive call? Any help is appreciated.

This is a slightly different issue than my last question, [RecursionError when trying to save image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609920/recursionerror-when-trying-to-save-image). Below are some properties of the image files I used which may or may not be relevant.

Successful image properties:

- 3888x2592 JPEG RGB
- 1920x1280 PNG RGB

Unsuccessful image properties:

- 360x720 PNG RGBA

*models.py*

```py
import hashlib
import os
import re

from base64 import b16encode
from functools import partial
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from django.db import models

from mtm.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Person(models.Model):
    prefix = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=5)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    suffix = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=5)
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='people/')
    _image_hash = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=16)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(editable=False, null=True, default=None, upload_to='people/')
    _thumbnail_hash = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=16)
    bio = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            self.generate_thumbnail()
            self.hash_thumbnail()
            self.resize_image()
            self.hash_image()

        self.bio = re.sub(r'(\r\n){2,}', '\r\n', self.bio)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_thumbnail(self):
        img = Image.open(self.image).convert('RGB')
        width, height = img.size
        max_longest, max_shortest = 300, 250

        if not self.thumbnail and (width >= height and (width > max_longest or height > max_shortest)) or (height > width and (height > max_longest or width > max_shortest)):
            if width > height:
                if (height * max_longest/ width) > max_shortest:
                    new_height = max_shortest
                    new_width = int(width * new_height / height)
                else:
                    new_width = max_longest
                    new_height = int(height * new_width / width)
            else:
                if (width * max_longest / height) > max_shortest:
                    new_width = max_shortest
                    new_height = int(height * new_width / width)
                else:
                    new_height = max_longest
                    new_width = int(width * new_height / height)

            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img_file = BytesIO()
            img.save(img_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)

            new_name = 'thumbnail_' + self.image.name.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
            self.thumbnail.save(new_name, img_file)

    def hash_thumbnail(self, block_size=65536):
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        filename = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.thumbnail.name

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            for buf in iter(partial(f.read, block_size), b''):
                hasher.update(buf)

            if not self.thumbnail_hash or self.thumbnail_hash != hasher.hexdigest().lower():
                self._thumbnail_hash = hasher.digest()
                self.thumbnail.name = 'people/' + hasher.hexdigest().lower() + '.jpg'
                new_filename = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.thumbnail.name
                os.rename(filename, new_filename)

    def resize_image(self):
        img = Image.open(self.image).convert('RGB')
        width, height = img.size
        max_longest, max_shortest = 960, 720

        if (width >= height and (width > max_longest or height > max_shortest)) or (height > width and (height > max_longest or width > max_shortest)):
            if width > height:
                if (height * max_longest/ width) > max_shortest:
                    new_height = max_shortest
                    new_width = int(width * new_height / height)
                else:
                    new_width = max_longest
                    new_height = int(height * new_width / width)
            else:
                if (width * max_longest / height) > max_shortest:
                    new_width = max_shortest
                    new_height = int(height * new_width / width)
                else:
                    new_height = max_longest
                    new_width = int(width * new_height / height)

            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img_file = BytesIO()
            img.save(img_file, 'JPEG', quality=90)

            new_name = self.image.name.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
            self.image.save(new_name, img_file)

    def hash_image(self, block_size=65536):
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        filename = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.image.name

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            for buf in iter(partial(f.read, block_size), b''):
                hasher.update(buf)

            if not self.image_hash or self.image_hash != hasher.hexdigest().lower():
                self._image_hash = hasher.digest()
                self.image.name = 'people/' + hasher.hexdigest().lower() + '.jpg'
                new_filename = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.image.name
                os.rename(filename, new_filename)

    @property
    def image_hash(self):
        return str(b16encode(self._image_hash).lower(), 'utf-8') if self._image_hash else None

    @property
    def thumbnail_hash(self):
        return str(b16encode(self._thumbnail_hash).lower(), 'utf-8') if self._thumbnail_hash else None

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'people'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to @soloidx's answer, I ended up moving image operations to a new method outside of `save()`.

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bio = re.sub(r'(\r\n){2,}', '\r\n', self.bio)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def image_ops(self):
        self.generate_thumbnail()
        self.hash_thumbnail()
        self.resize_image()
        self.hash_image()
```

Then `image_ops()` is called in the view just before calling `save()`. No infinite calls to `save()`! I would still like to know why the infinite calls were only happening with certain images, but perhaps some mysteries are better left unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save)

> FieldFile.save(name, content, save=True)
>   This method takes a filename and file contents and passes them to the storage class for the field, then associates the stored file with the model field. If you want to manually associate file data with FileField instances on your model, the save() method is used to persist that file data.
>
> Takes two required arguments: name which is the name of the file, and content which is an object containing the file’s contents. **The optional save argument controls whether or not the model instance is saved after the file associated with this field has been altered**. Defaults to True.

So, if you want to avoid duplicates you should change your:

```
self.thumbnail.save(new_name, img_file)
```

by:

```
self.thumbnail.save(new_name, img_file, save=False)
```

this is also aplicable for the `self.image` in the `resize_image` method.

Comment: That's great, except I need to actually save the file at some point.

Comment: I understand, but the last `super().save()` should save these two fields

Comment: No, `img_file` is outside the scope of `super().save()`.

Comment: I get `FileNotFoundError` when I try to open the file in `hash_image`.

Comment: What I'll do is move the image operations to a new method outside of `save()`.